# VxWorks and Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, vxworks, tftp

I am setting up a virtual machine with virtualbox with vxworks 7 as guest.

I follow the guide from the windriver documentation but I think something is missing. So, I am able to create successfully the virtual machine, but I need to load the boot file `vxWorks`, (created in the multi-stage boot application) using `tftp`.

So far, so good, I don't know if I should load the boot image using `tftp` or not though. The thing is that I have no `ssh` access, therefore I cannot debug any application.

I have tried rebuilding with all the SSH features enabled in the `vsb.vxconfig` file (`IPNET_SSH`, `OPENSSL`, `SEC_CRYPTO`, `USER_MANAGEMENT`, etc) and still no luck with ssh. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PXE TFTP is a primitive protocol which has exactly nothing to do with SSH2.

See the [documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#nat-tftp):

> **6.3.2. PXE booting with NAT**
>
> PXE booting is now supported in NAT mode. The NAT DHCP server provides a boot file name of the form `vmname.pxe` if the directory `TFTP` exists in the directory where the user's `VirtualBox.xml` file is kept. It is the responsibility of the user to provide `vmname.pxe`.

Create a directory called `TFTP`  inside `%appdata%\.VirtualBox` or `~/.VirtualBox` and put the .pxe file into there... this should then be loaded when booting from PXE. The default IP of that TFTP server would be `10.0.2.4`.